# Trying to read a file lines into an object array

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

I have a file thats lade out like so:

```
Jim Smith, male, 12, 09/98/1992
Ben Todd, male, 12, 09/98/1992
```

I want to be able to read these lines into my person object, and place these objects into an array.

Here is my code. Is it currently throwing a **NullPointerException**.

Any ideas?

```
public class Main {
    public static ArrayList<String> catagories = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("manipulate-data.txt");
        System.out.println(file.getName() + " file exists = " + file.exists());

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        int iteration = 0;
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (iteration == 0) {

                String[] columns = line.split(",");
                for (String column : columns) {
                    catagories.add(column);
                }
                iteration++;
                continue;
            }
            sortFile(line);
        }

        bufferedReader.close();

    }

    private static void sortFile(String line) {
        String[] columns = line.split(",");
        Person[] newPerson = new Person[4];
        int i = 0;
        for (String column : columns) {
            newPerson[i].setName(column);
            newPerson[i].setSex(column);
            newPerson[i].setAge(column);
            newPerson[i].setBirth(column);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give us a traceback on the NPE?

Answer (score 3):

```
  Person [] newPerson = new Person[4];
```

The above line is the declaration of `Person` array. You need to initialize `Person` inside for loop to avoid `NPE`.

```
int i = 0;
for (String column : columns) {

   newPerson[i] = new Person();
   .....
}
```

**Edit**

In your code, you should read `Person` properties line by line. And use `ArrayList` instead of array, as you may not know the line number of file for array size.

```
List<Person> persons= new ArrayList<Person>(); // Diamond <> operator for Java 7 
 String line;
 while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
  persons.add(readPerson(line));
 }

....
```

At `readPerson` method, you should split your line by comma `,` and read `Person` properties and return  `Person` object.

```
private static Person readPerson(String line) {
String[] columns = line.split(",");
Person  newPerson = new Person();

 newPerson.setName(columns[0]);
 newPerson.setSex(columns[1]);
 newPerson.setAge(columns[2]);
 newPerson.setBirth(columns[3]);

  return newPerson;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves the NPE. But its not reading each category into the right part.

Comment: Ie, all the parameters at newPerson[0] are equal to the name rather than, name, sex, age, dob.

Comment: @user2091819, Your code has logical array. I will edit my answser with details

Comment: This looks like what I need but I'm getting an error at the "list" line asking me if I want to change JRE to 1.7? EDIT: Tried chaining it to arrayList

Comment: Don't need Jdk 1.7. Just declare List like `List<Person> persons= new ArrayList<Person>();`

Comment: Okay, thats working fine, but when i then got display the newPerson at a certain index, it is underlining the newPerson part. Here is the code I am using:  System.out.print(newPerson[1].toString());

Comment: Got it to output, but its exactly the same as before. The categories aren't aligning.

Comment: SOLVED IT!  private static Person readPerson(String line) {
  String[] columns = line.split(",");
  Person  newPerson = new Person();
int i = 0;
  for (String column : columns) {
      newPerson.setName(columns[i]);
      newPerson.setSex(columns[i+1]);
      newPerson.setAge(columns[i+2]);
      newPerson.setBirth(columns[i+3]);

  }
 
   return newPerson;